# XPath - Compare values from different documents

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

This is my XPath expression

```
$XMLDESCRIPTION/myItems/ITEM[@TYPE="ok" and boolean($XML/myElements/element[ends-with(Description/@code, string(@CODE))])]
```

The ITEM node in $XMLDESCRIPTION has an attribute called CODE and i want to check in $XML if there is an "element" with a Description/@code that matches the @CODE from $XMLDESCRIPTION

The question is: how do I access the @CODE attribute in the $XML part of my filter?

extra info:

1. I'm working in an XSLT context (I use stylevision)
2. The expression works fine if I type a
   fixed value in the "ends-with" part instead of string(@CODE)

**XML**
This is my $XMLDESCRIPTION snippet

```
<myItems>
    <ITEM CODE="003423" TYPE="ok">Hello</ITEM>
    <ITEM CODE="003123" TYPE="ok">hello12</ITEM>
    <ITEM CODE="003223" TYPE="notok">Hellollo</ITEM>
    <ITEM CODE="005423" TYPE="notok">Hellolol</ITEM>
    <ITEM CODE="003424" TYPE="ok">HellossSSSDDFFSQSSQDFQSDF</ITEM>
    <ITEM CODE="003442" TYPE="ok">Helloee</ITEM>
    <ITEM CODE="003342" TYPE="ok">Hellodd</ITEM>
    <ITEM CODE="008900" TYPE="ok">Helloee</ITEM>
    <ITEM CODE="003888" TYPE="inprogress">Helloaa</ITEM>
</myItems>
```

this is a snippet from my $XML document

```
<myElements>
    <element><Description code="009999">myinformation</Description></element>
    <element><Description code="008888">myinformation</Description></element>
    <element><Description code="003424">myinformation</Description></element>
    <element><Description code="002222">myinformation</Description></element>
    <element><Description code="003333">myinformation</Description></element>
    <element><Description code="005555">myinformation</Description></element>
</myElements>
```

With those two xml examples my outcome should be "HellossSSSDDFFSQSSQDFQSDF" because that's the only element that has an existing description node with a code "003424" in $XML so that's the only ITEM element's content that the xpath should get.

Comment: I think you need to provide an XML sample and explain which node / attribute you want to dig out with the XML. Hard to tell from your question above what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added some xml to clarify my problem

Comment: Please also add some XSLT code. It could be there is a much easier way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're missing the `current()` function.

```
$XMLDESCRIPTION/myItems/ITEM[
  @TYPE="ok" 
  and $XML/myElements/element/Description[
    ends-with(@code, current()/@CODE)
  ]
]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i use a dynamic table (sort of loop) in stylevision. I'm not too familiar with pure XSLT and I cant tell what that would look like rendered to XSLT. I used the current()/@CODE in my dynamic table and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath should dig out the code attribute from the $XML document:-

```
/myElements/element/Description[@code]
```